# NPM not installing packages but yarn is working

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I cloned a starter code of express and when I ran `npm install` to install packages from "packagejson",  it showed me an error but when the same is done using Yarn i.e `yarn install`, it installed every package successfully. I have gotten this problem a few times earlier also, and was wondering what could be the reason...??

The error that I was getting was:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'binary-extensions'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/locusrags/locusnotes/node_modules/is-binary-path/index.js:3:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

even i faced the same issue and i solved it with the following solution

> please check **.nprmc** is present or not with the updated keys

hoping, this helped you.